# How to generate feed for custom template

Tags: wp-query, templates, page-template, feed

I created a custom template with its own custom query. Use case: a page for just sticky posts.

Added `sticky.php` to the theme with

```
/**
 * Template Name: Sticky
 */
```

and the following loop:

```
$query = new WP_Query(array('post__in' => get_option( 'sticky_posts' ), 'posts_per_page'=>10, 'ignore_sticky_posts'=>1, 'paged' => ( get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1 ) ));
if($query->have_posts()) : while($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
get_template_part('excerpt'); 
endwhile; endif;
```

Next, I add an empty page called Sticky with `sticky.php` as template.

Now, when I go to example.com/sticky, the selection works fine, pagination included. However, `example.com/sticky/feed` doesn't show a proper feed, instead it has an empty comments feed, as if it were a post.

So what should I do to have it output a feed of posts, like all other archive pages do?

Answer (score 1):

Start with adding your new feed name and custom function through [add_feed](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_feed), then dont't forget to [flush](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/flush_rules) rewrite rules (just once).

You can find several [WordPress functions](https://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_Feeds) that will help your formatting the Feed XML.